# scrape images from a particular e-commerce website's link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, imageurl

I am scraping a e-commerce website for experience. I am currently facing a problem scraping images of a product.
I have scraped the html codes for all present images of a product but can't extract the **link** from that html code.

the code i tried is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl='https://www.preispirat24.com/neu-im-september/'
baseforimages='https://www.preispirat24.com/'
headers={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
   
}   

productlinks=[]
for x in range(0,1,1):    
    r=requests.get('https://www.preispirat24.com/neu-im-september/?page={}'.format(x))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='title-description')
    item='title-description'

    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a',href=True):
            productlinks.append(link['href'])
            a=(link['href'])
            
            

#testlink='https://www.preispirat24.com/Lufterfrischer/axe-air-fresher/axe-mini-vent-dark-temptation-air-freshener-lufterfrischer-6er-t-dsp.html'
insultlist=[]
images=[]
for link in productlinks:
    b=link
    try:
        r=requests.get(link,headers=headers)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        title=soup.find('h1',class_="product-info-title-desktop hidden-xs hidden-sm").text.strip()
        description=soup.find(class_='tab-body active',itemprop="description").text.strip()
        itemnumber=soup.find('span',itemprop="model").text.strip()

        images=soup.find_all(class_='align-vertical')
        print(images)
        #print (images['src'])
    except:
        print('----')
    insult={
        'title':title,
        'description':description,
        'itemnumber':itemnumber,
        'images':images,
        'productlink':b
    }
   
    insultlist.append(insult)
df=pd.DataFrame(insultlist)
print('Saving :',title)
print(df.head)
df.to_csv('3veerapreispirat24.csv')
```

**The output I get is something like:**

```
<img alt="Mobile Preview: 99671" data-magnifier-src="images/product_images/original_images/99671(1).jpg" src="images/product_images/gallery_images/99671(1).jpg" title="Mobile Preview: 99671"/>
</div>, <div class="align-vertical">
<img alt="Mobile Preview: 99671" data-magnifier-src="images/product_images/original_images/99671.jpg" src="images/product_images/gallery_images/99671.jpg" title="Mobile Preview: 99671"/>
</div>]
```

**The Output I want:**

```
images/product_images/original_images/99671(1).jpg
images/product_images/gallery_images/99671(1).jpg
images/product_images/original_images/99671.jpg
images/product_images/gallery_images/99671.jpg"
```

Note I have tried: `print(images['src'])`
it resulted exception printing ---

Example Product Link From the product-images to be extracted

[Link Here](https://www.preispirat24.com/Verbrauchsartikel/Hygiene-Artikel-127/mund-nasen-maske-3-lagig-pink-mit-nasenbuegel-ohrschlaufen-einheitsgroesse-10-stuec.html)

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get image URLs from the link, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.preispirat24.com/Verbrauchsartikel/Hygiene-Artikel-127/mund-nasen-maske-3-lagig-pink-mit-nasenbuegel-ohrschlaufen-einheitsgroesse-10-stuec.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for img in soup.select('#product_thumbnail_swiper [data-magnifier-src]'):
    print('https://www.preispirat24.com/' + img['data-magnifier-src'])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.preispirat24.com/images/product_images/original_images/99649mix.jpg
https://www.preispirat24.com/images/product_images/original_images/99649.jpg
https://www.preispirat24.com/images/product_images/original_images/99649_0.jpg
https://www.preispirat24.com/images/product_images/original_images/99649_1.jpg
```

---

EDIT: To save product to csv, you can do:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.preispirat24.com/Verbrauchsartikel/Hygiene-Artikel-127/mund-nasen-maske-3-lagig-pink-mit-nasenbuegel-ohrschlaufen-einheitsgroesse-10-stuec.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')


title=soup.find('h1',class_="product-info-title-desktop hidden-xs hidden-sm").text.strip()
description=soup.find(class_='tab-body active',itemprop="description").text.strip()
itemnumber=soup.find('span',itemprop="model").text.strip()

images = []
for img in soup.select('#product_thumbnail_swiper [data-magnifier-src]'):
    images.append('https://www.preispirat24.com/' + img['data-magnifier-src'])
    # print('https://www.preispirat24.com/' + img['data-magnifier-src'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'title':title,
        'description':description,
        'itemnumber':itemnumber,
        'images':[images],
        'productlink':url
    })

df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                               title  ...                                        productlink
0  Mund Nasen Maske 3-lagig PINK mit Nasenbügel, ...  ...  https://www.preispirat24.com/Verbrauchsartikel...

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```

And saves `data.csv`

Comment: Respected , I really apperciate your work , it helped me alot.
But the issue is i have to store all these image links to a .cvs file . As the above mentioned code doesn't work for saving image links to a cvs file. Much apericiated.Thanks for help

Comment: waiting for your response. Thank You

Comment: Thank you so much love your work. Much apperciated. God bless you.

Comment: I am looping through each product of url:
https://www.preispirat24.com/neu-im-september/?page=0

But it donot save image links again :( and not  appending the data .
The source code can be found below can you please modify it. It will hardly take 30 seconds for you.  
https://repl.it/repls/GiantFeistyDeletions#main.py

looking for help @AndrejKesely

Thanks

Comment: please help. I am stuck and tring since 3 days :(

Answer (score 0):

Your `images` variable is an array of HTML `<div>` elements from what I can see. You should iterate over each item in the array, find the `<img>`, then get its `src` tag, eg:

```py
for element in images:
    url = element.find("img").get("src")
```